# Implementation restrictions of "this" keyword in C++, as it relates to dangerous but functional example

Tags: c++, this

I know that the value of a given `this` cannot be determined at compile time. I am left wondering that once a given object is allocated and constructed, is the value of `this` cached, or is there literally a runtime evaluation of the expression every use? Here is the specific example that motivates my question. Be warned, this violates about every OOP doctrine and protection feature C++ aims to uphold.

```
int main()
{
    string s1 = string("I am super a super long string named s1, and won't be SSO");
    string s2 = string("I am super a super long string named s2, and won't be SSO");

    byte* s1interface = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&s1);
    byte* s2interface = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&s2);

    static_assert(sizeof s1 == sizeof s2);

    for(int offset(0); offset < sizeof s1; ++offset)
    {
        *(s1interface + offset) ^= *(s2interface + offset);
        *(s2interface + offset) ^= *(s1interface + offset);
        *(s1interface + offset) ^= *(s2interface + offset);
    }

    cout << s1 << '\n' << s2 << "\n\n\n";

    return 0;
}
//outputs:
//I am super a super long string **named s2**, and won't be SSO
//I am super a super long string **named s1**, and won't be SSO
//(The emphasis on the output strings was added by me to highlight the identity change)
```

I want to start off by saying this program not only compiles, but produces that output consistently. My question is not predicated on why/how this works.

The way I see it, any internal variables, even those managing heap memory, will be transplanted as soon as the objects are (re)-fully-formed. However, I envision a hypothetical scenario in which `this` is queried by an object and then stored internally. After the object transplant operation, `&me` would not coincide with a `this` that was queried and stored upon original construction, which would seriously corrupt any operations that use `this` coupled with any runtime address reflection. Though this should never be done, and all bets are off if anyone dares do anything so heinous with any object theirs or otherwise, does the Standard dictate a persistent evaluation of `this`, or just for `this` to do what it says under the assumption the object will only occupy the space where it is put?

EDIT: Let me explain it another way, If during runtime, the object has a hidden and internal `this` that gets written once it is allocated, and all subsequent reads of `this` read the stored value, after the transplant `&object` and `this` will not be the same. That is clearly not how it is implemented by my compiler, but I want to know if that is by conformance or by luck.

Comment: An object that stores a pointer to one of its elements will not be in a sane state after this kind of operation. This is why assignment operators were invented.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not worried about the object, I'm worried about how `this` is implemented by the compiler. Is where the object is a question that gets asked and answered every time, or assumed to be static once answered once.

Comment: `this` is a pointer, which is passed as hidden argument when you invoke any method from class

Comment: @IłyaBursov I realize that. However, its value is not expected to change by proper use of the language. Is its value stored once determined by allocation, or is its value queried?

Comment: @schulmaster code `a.method(arg);` is actually `Class:method(&a, arg);`, if you understand this - then you can see that it neither stored nor queried, address of variable is "evaluated" every time, but as soon as binary code does not have any variables, it has only addresses - it just passed

Comment: @IłyaBursov Can you link me to the section of the standard that specifies that abstraction?

Comment: @schulmaster it's not in the standard (the standard says what to do and not how to implement it).  It's just how most (all) of the current compilers implement calling methods.  Use one of the online compiler explorers to see how method calls are translated into assembler.

Comment: @schulmaster what abstraction you mean?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in some versions of MSVC++ 32-bit, `a.method(arg)` was not strictly equivalent to `Class::method(&a, arg)` but instead the `this` pointer was passed through the `ecx` register while all arguments were passed on the stack as usual.  So, the rule of thumb that Ilya Bursov's comment presented is highly dependent on C++ calling conventions and isn't necessarily universal.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I figured a caveat like that would exist. I know that that calling convention is the Python way, but Python is in your face about it with the requisite `self`.

Comment: I think if you tried to use a custom class like `struct A; struct B { B(A& a) : parent(a) { }; A& parent; }; struct A { B child; A() : child(*this) { }; void verify() { assert(&(child.parent) == this); };` then you would indeed get an assertion failure after byte-swapping two `A` objects and then calling `a1.verify()` on one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I reached out to Stephan Lavavej ([Stephan's website](https://nuwen.net/stl.html)), who maintains the Standard Library implementation for Microsoft, with this question. I will post his answer below. I do want to point out that user **HAL9000** was essentially right with his answer, but since Stephan's was so thorough, I'll post it, and eventually designate it as the official answer(*it's hard to get more official than the words of someone who actually maintains a Big 3 implementation of the Standard*). If you find this answer informative, HAL9000's answer has a visual example to reinforce the idea.

Stephan's Words:

> You shouldn't think of the "this" pointer as being stored within an object. The implicit parameter mental model is the most accurate one.
>   When a function x() calls a member function Meow::y() on a Meow object m, x() has to know the address of m already. It might be a local variable (x() knows where all of its local variables live on the stack), it might be a dereferenced pointer (if m is *ptr, ptr points to m), it might be passed via reference (references are not pointers, but they effectively have the same location information as pointers), it might be an element on an array (if m is arr[idx], then arr + idx points to m), etc. So Meow::y() will be implicitly passed the address of m, which becomes "this" within the member function.
>
> Crucially, if you have a struct that contains plain old data (e.g. a bunch of ints) and you swap the contents of two structs, the objects don't change identity - only their contents. If I take all of your stuff in your house and swap it with the stuff within someone else's house, the locations of the houses are unchanged. (In C++, objects can't migrate from one memory address to another - the most you can do is create a separate object, move all the stuff, tell anyone who cares about the old location to instead point to the new location, and then destroy the empty shell of the original object - that's move semantics, basically.)
>
> Because "this" isn't actually stored anywhere, it has zero cost, which is useful to know. (This is outside virtual member functions, which do make objects pay a vptr cost, but that's much more advanced.)
>
> Hope this helps,
>   STL

Answer (score 2):

The value of `this` is never "queried" by an object. It is passed to (non-static) object methods as an implicit parameter.

Supposed you have this c++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class mystring
{
public:
   char *data;  
   void print();
};

void mystring::print() 
{
   fputs(this->data, stdout);
}

void
main()
{
   mystring s = {"Hello World"};  

   s.print();
}
```

Now it looks like the method `print` does not take any parameters, but actually it does, a pointer to the object `s`. So the compiler will generate code equivalent to this c program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mystring
{
   char *data;  
};

void mystring_print(struct mystring *this) 
{
   fputs(this->data, stdout);
}

void
main()
{
   mystring s = {"Hello World"};  

   mystring_print(&s);
}
```

So there is nothing magical with the `this` pointer. It is just a boring parameter as any other. Things get a little more interesting with virtual methods, but the handling of `this` stays the same

Comment: Is this specified by the standard? If not, there is reason not to trust this rationale, though sensical and common. See Daniel's comment above...

Comment: It must be passed as a hidden parameter, otherwise how can the method `print` know which object it is supposed to work with? If it were to query the object, it would already need a pointer to do the query on the right object. Exactly how `this` is passed as a parameter is probably implementation dependant.

Comment: This a good description of what's usually done, but I believe @schulmaster is correct to be wary. the C++ standard tries very hard to keep it's hands off the actual implementation details. While it could be buried elsewhere, in **[class.this]** the Standard makes no mention of how `this` makes it into the method. If you can harness black magic or teleportation, it's probably just as legal as a hidden parameter. In a way this is like stacks, heaps, and v-tables. They are almost always what's used, but the Standard makes little mention of them.

Comment: @user4581301 - As far as I know, the standard does not say much on how to pass any parameter. They could all be passed by black magic I would guess. The `this` parameter is not special in this regard.

Comment: That's true. The actual rules of parameter passing have to be left murky to handle the many different calling conventions floating around out there. That's a different matter from "Is `this` guaranteed to be a parameter?" though.

Comment: @HAL9000 If I as a compiler writer know that a given object is intended to stay where it is put, I can conclude that once I know `this` once, I know it for the object lifetime. If I can remove 64bits of functioncall overhead based on this assumption, and the standard doesn't say I can't, why wouldn't I? What it comes down to is can an external `&object` EVER evaluate to a different value from the same object's internal `this' at any moment.

Comment: @user4581301 - Define parameter. If you mean "Something that is written in a parameter list of a valid function call", then no, the method may expect to find the value of `this` somewhere else. But if you by parameter mean "Information passed by the caller to the callee", the yes, `this` must be a parameter. Anything else is not possible.

Comment: @schulmaster - The value of `this` is can not always be the same value as &object (think of subclasses, but here you should be able to recover the value of &object with dynamic casting). But the value of `this` for the same (sub)object remains always the same across method calls. Otherwise you would not be able to safely pass it around to other functions. By being "The Same" I mean being able to pass it around and compare it with other pointers of the same type. By trying to do any low level interpretation of of the bits in `this` you should not depend on `this` having a specific value.